# Construct a ring isomorphism and its inverse

Tags: ring-isomorphism

I have to construct a ring isomorphism $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/\langle x^2+2xy+y^2-529,x+3y-1\rangle \cong \mathbb{C}\times \mathbb C$ and its inverse.

I tried to find a function with $\langle x^2+2xy+y^2-529,x+3y-1\rangle$ as a Kernel but couldn't figure it out. I also don't quite understand what $\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}$ actually is other than it means  the cartesian product of $\mathbb C$ with itself

It feels like a fairly simple question with a simple solution but I'm getting nowhere. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm currently tearing my hair out trying to do anything with it.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: A morphism from $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ to a ring is completely determined by specifying what happens to the constants, and what happens to $x$ and to $y$. So figure out a way to make sure that once you specify that, you get precisely the kernel you want.

Comment: $\mathbb C\times\mathbb C$ is a ring whose underlying set is the cartesian product, like you said, so to understand it you just need to know how to add and multiply. And this is done coordinate-wise: $(a,b)+(c,d)=(a\!+\!c,b\!+\!d)$, and $(a,b)\cdot(c,d)=(ac,bd)$. (This ring is not a field or anything like that; for example, $(1,0)\cdot(0,1)=(0,0)$, the zero element.)

Comment: Following the comment by @ArturoMagidin I cheated a bit and [asked WolframAlpha to simultaneously solve these two equations](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x%5E2%2B2xy%2By%5E2%E2%88%92529%3D0%2Cx%2B3y%E2%88%921%3D0) (although it wouldn't take much to solve them by hand). It's precisely because there are $2$ solutions that you get an isomorphism to $\mathbb C^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be $ℂ[x, y]$ and let $I$ be the given ideal in $A$.
Let $J ≔ ⟨x + 3y - 1⟩$, which is an ideal in $A$ with $A ⊇ I ⊇ J$.
By the third isomorphism theorem we have
$$
  A / I ≅ (A / J) / (I / J) \,.
$$

The quotient $A / J$ is easy to determine:
modding out the polynomial $x + 3y - 1$ identifies $x$ with $1 - 3y$.
More explicitly, we have the isomorphism
$$
  φ \colon A / J ≅ ℂ[y] \,, \quad
  [x] \mapsto 1 - 3y \, \quad
  [y] \mapsto y \,.
  \tag{1}
$$
Under the isomorphism $φ$ the ideal $I / J$ of $A / J$ corresponds to an ideal $K$ in $ℂ[y]$, and the isomorphism $φ$ descends to an isomorphism
$$
  (A / J) / (I / J) ≅ ℂ[y] / K \,.
$$
The ideal $I / J$ is generated by the two residue classes $[x^2 + 2xy + y^2 - 529]$ and $[x + 3y - 1]$, whence the ideal $K$ is generated by $φ([x^2 + 2xy + y^2 - 529])$ and $φ([x + 3y - 1])$.
The second generator of $K$ is $0$ because already $[x + 3y - 1] = 0$ in $A / J$ (after all, we modded out this generator when we formed $A / J$).
The first generator of $K$ is
$$
  (1 - 3y)^2 + 2(1 - 3y)y + y^2 - 529
  =
  4 y^2 - 4 y - 528
  =
  4 ⋅ (y^2 - y - 132) \,.
$$
The factor $4$ is invertible in $ℂ[y]$, whence $K$ is generated by the single polynomial $y^2 - y - 132$.
We have the decomposition
$$
  y^2 - y - 132
  =
  (y - 12) (y + 11) \,.
$$
It now follows from the Chinese Remainder Theorem (for principal ideal domains) that
\begin{align*}
  ℂ[y] / K
  &=
  ℂ[y] / ⟨y^2 - y - 132⟩ \\
  &=
  ℂ[y] / ⟨(y - 12)(y + 11)⟩ \\
  &≅
  ℂ[y] / ⟨y - 12⟩ × ℂ[y] / ⟨y + 11⟩ \tag{2} \\
  &≅
  ℂ × ℂ \,.
\end{align*}
We use here that
$$
  ℂ[x] / ⟨x - a⟩ ≅ ℂ \,, \quad
  [p] \mapsto p(a) \tag{3} 
$$
for every $a ∈ ℂ$.

---

If you wish to write down an *explicit* isomorphism between $A/I$ and $ℂ × ℂ$ then you’ll need to trace the images of $[x]$ and $[y]$ under the above sequence of isomorphisms
\begin{align*}
  A / I
  &≅ (A / J) / (I / J) \\
  &≅ ℂ[y] / K \\
  &≅ ℂ[y] / ⟨y - 12⟩ × ℂ[y] / ⟨y + 11⟩ \\
  &≅ ℂ × ℂ \,.
\end{align*}
We already have explicit formulas for the steps $(1)$ and $(3)$, and the isomorphism $(2)$ is given by $[p] \mapsto ([p], [p])$.
We thus find that
$$
  [x]
  \mapsto [[x]]
  \mapsto [1 - 3y]
  \mapsto ([1 - 3y], [1 - 3y])
  \mapsto (1 - 3 ⋅ 12, 1 - 3 ⋅ (-11))
  =       (-35, 34)
$$
and
$$
  [y]
  \mapsto [[y]]
  \mapsto [y]
  \mapsto ([y], [y])
  \mapsto (12, -11) \,.
$$
The overall isomorphism between $A / I$ and $ℂ × ℂ$ is thus given by sending $[x]$ to $(-35, 34)$ and $[y]$ to $(12, -11)$.